# Disable javamail email address validation

Tags: email, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

Id like my application to have bare minimum 'To' email address validation, that is only empty string is considered to be invalid. All the below strings are to be considered as valid email addresses from my application perspective:

- adas.assa.com
- sdaassa.com
- sada

Im using spring-boot-mail starter to develop my application, and MimeMessageHelper to construct the mail message. And java mail api would issue sendFailedException Invalid Address, when I tried to send email to those addresses. From my digging it seems that there are already built in email address validations. Is there any way that I can disable the email address validations, so that my application still send email to those addresses?

---

Update since @Bill Shannon:-
I've updated my properties file as so:
spring.mail.properties.mail.mime.address.strict=false

Im still getting the error:

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: 
>   javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
>   nested exception is:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address

Im not sure if it has to do with how I pass the session properties as you @Bill mentioned, or coming from exhange server address validation(can we tell from the error?).

---

Update after checking with exchanger server admin.

It works. The error received actually issue by email server. You have to get your email server to disable email address validation to make it work.

Comment: No matter how much you wish otherwise, those aren't fully qualified email addresses, and it's impossible to send mail to them.

Comment: @duskwuff Yes I know. But our lead design the application to behave in such way. His reasoning was the source application that provide the email addresses is responsible for email address format validation, and our application concern is just to make sure the email address field is not empty.

Comment: His reasoning is unsound. The target mail server will also validate them, and there is no reason why JavaMail should not also be permitted to do so. Specifically, your 'requirement' to have domain names accepted as email addresses *at the point you invoke it* is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Session property [`mail.mime.address.strict`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.address.strict) to "false".  Still, it's up to your mail server whether it will accept those addresses.

Comment: I've update my properties file as so:  
spring.mail.properties.mail.mime.address.strict=false

And still getting the same error:  
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;  

Im not sure if it has to do with the exchange server setting(can we tell from the error?), or the way  I set the properties.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: Upon checking with exchange server admin, we have confirmed that the error actually coming exchange server. Thanks for your help.